# ngModel não exibe valor campo dinamico

Tags: angularjs

Em uma função que inclui campos dinâmicos, não estou conseguindo exibir o valor do produto quando digitado.

Se faço somente com um input exibe valor normal mas com os campos dinâmicos não consigo exibir, segue o código:

```js
$scope.somaOS = function(valor) {
  $scope.totalOS = parseFloat(valor);
};

$scope.inputs = [];
$scope.add = function(valor, desc) {
  var dataObj = {
    desc: desc,
    valor: valor
  };
  $scope.inputs.push(dataObj);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <small class="d-block"><b>VALOR PRODUTOS</b></small>
  <span class="text-info font-weight-bold display-30">{{valor | currency}}</span>
</div>

<div id="produto" class="tab-pane">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mt-5 p-2">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adicionar Campo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 input-group-sm">
      <label class="col-form-label">Descrição Produto</label>
      <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
        <input class="form-control text-uppercase mb-1" ng-model="input.desc" name="upOSProd[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 input-group-sm">
      <label class="col-form-label">Valor Produto</label>
      <div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
        <input class="form-control text-uppercase mb-1 input-group-sm" ng-model="input.valor" name="upOSProdValor[]" money-mask ng-keyup="somaOS(valor)">
      </div>
      {{valor}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o erro possa estar nessas linhas:

```
<input class="form-control text-uppercase mb-1 input-group-sm" ng-model="input.valor" name="upOSProdValor[]" money-mask ng-keyup="somaOS(valor)">

<input class="form-control text-uppercase mb-1" ng-model="input.desc" name="upOSProd[]">
```

Você já tentou substituir **input.desc** por **inputs.desc** ou então colocar o valor por inteiro ( $scope.inputs.desc )

Comment: Obs: poderia verificar se é isso, se não for comentar vou editar a resposta para alguma outra coisa que você possa tentar fazer

Comment: da forma que você falou deu certo (inputs.desc), mas como os inputs são dinâmicos quando digito em um campo altera o outro também pois os inputs sempre terão o mesmo ng-model. Qual a melhor maneira para resolver isso

Comment: Eu recomento dar uma olhada nesse vídeo: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlVxG2lG1Tk&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G&index=10> pois explica quando usar o ngModel, Property Binding e Interpolação

Comment: Outra aula dela que recomendo <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WF28rLBangw&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G&index=12> Acho que essa aula se adequa mais a sua necessidade aproximadamente aos 6 minutos explica uma boa forma de fazer o que você quer